# Can not connect to Db- Dump using codeception

Tags: pdo, codeception

I am struggling to use the db functionality of codeception framework. The error i am getting is

**Db: could not find mysql driver while creating PDO connection**

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
      enabled: [Db, PhpBrowser]
      config:
           Db:
              dsn: "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db"
              user: 'root'
              password:
              populate: true
              cleanup: true
              dump: 'tests/_data/Dump20180423.sql'

           PhpBrowser:
              url :
```

1. My `acceptance.suite.yaml` file is set like this.
2. Also my dump file has the `CREATE TABLE` command inside.
3. The path for Mysql is already set in the environmental variables path.
4. The pdo extensions are set inside my php.ini file

I guess it's a problem with the dsn as it fails before validating my user credentials. Also my mysql works fine. I have projects that i use PDO connection and they work without any issue.

I tried every solution i could find but still getting the same error. Thank you in advance for any help!!!

Comment: You do not have the appropriate driver, so you need to install it. What research have you done and what have you attempted to install a new driver?

Comment: That's my question. The visual c++ that was a solution to a similar problem is already build-in XAMPP which i am using. Also the fact that my PDO works fine with other php projects lead me to a conclusion that it's not a driver missing, it's that this project, using codeception framework can not "see" the mysql driver.

Comment: I do not know how your php is installed and what versions of pdo your other code and this framework uses. I would suggest to test if the particular php / pdo environment this project uses does have the pdo MySQL driver installed.

Comment: Does xampp use separate php.ini files for apache and cli? It is possible that pdo-mysql driver is not enabled in cli.

Comment: No the php.ini file is inside php folder and it's the one that includes all the configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after many hours/days i finally found out the solution to this. The problem was coming from my cygwin (linux console). While my php.ini file was fine and php info was sawing i had pdo_mysql installed and everything seemed like that, cygwin had a different opinion. I had to install pdo_mysql inside cygwin so the command :

`php vendor/bin/codecept run`  could connect to the database and work!!!

Typing `php -m` in my cygwin console showed me that i was missing this module (pdo_mysql).

After that the problem is solved and my tests work fine.